# Sending a form to a php script, that the user never knows or sees

Tags: php, email, background-process, performance

On my site, I have a feature that allows you to follow the updates of other users.  When a user makes a change to their info, anyone following him or her will be emailed of this change.

I have it set up so that the php changes the info in the database, then searches through the users contacts to see who is following him/her, and sends emails to those who are following notifying them of the change.

The problem I have run into since adding this notification feature, is that insead of the page loading (form posts to itself) and showing the change almost instantly, (depending on how many people are following a particular user) it can take a few munites for the page to load and show the update (because the php is sending all the emails before the page reloads).

How can I set it up, where the script to send the emails, is run somewhere in the background, and the user does not have to wait for the emails to send before the page reloads, and could possibly even exit out of the website and still have the emails send if still the script is still running?

P.S. All my programming and development skills have been self taught, so I don't know a lot of terminology..... You may have to dumb down your responses so that I will understand what you are talking about. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you very much for any help.

Comment: [gearman](http://www.php.net/gearman) seems a fine solution to offload the brunt of the task to non-webserver processes.

Comment: @gearman I am not sure what that means....

Comment: oh, hahahaha! Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thanks @Wrikken.

Comment: Hehe, well, gearman _does_ sound more like a username then an extension ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it takes several minutes just to send some emails, but anyway you can do this in at least four ways:

- Use ajax to send the form data to a separate script that sends the emails while the form posts normally
- Have the form script fork (`pcntl` required)
- Make an asynchronous request to your own page via php (either set a low timeout with cURL, or open a socket)
- Use `exec('script-that-sends-emails args >> some-other-file 2>&1 &');`

Comment: The reason it takes so long, is that users can set their notification to either receive an email or a text.  If they want to be sent a text, since I dont ask during sign up what service provider they have, I have the script run a for loop that just sends to the four main providers (verizon, att, sprint, tmobile) for that number.  This for loop is nested in a while loop that sends to all people following this particular user.  So if a user has 100 people following him or her, and they all want to be texted, the script is sending 400 emails before the page reloads.

Comment: It's rude to do that .. you should get a text messaging server.